# Making a matrix of lists by concatenating several arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, matrix, concatenation

I am trying to create a compiled list of every possible combination of several arrays. I have a background in matlab so I'm somewhat familiar with how loops and basic code principles work. However, I'm not sure what would be the most efficient way of compiling a list of several arrays into a matrix of these lists. I initially made a matrix of all possible combinations, but I realized it would take too much time to update each entry if I decided to add a component into one of the arrays. I tried to incorporate the push command to account for this along the lines of:

```
matrix=[array1, array2, array3]
var newMeat= 'pastrami'
matrix[1].push(bread[1] + '-' + newMeat + ....)
```

so I could input it from a ui but it got messy. For example, I have one base array:

```
bread=['rye', 'white', 'wheat']
```

and I want to make a list for each type combined with other arrays like

```
meat = [ 'roast beef', 'ham', 'turkey' ]
condiments = [ 'mayo', 'mustard','ketchup' ]
```

so it would look like this:

```
combinations = [ 'rye-roast beef-mayo',    'white-roast beef-mayo',  . 'wheat-roast beef-mayo' 
                 'rye-roast beef-mustard', 'white-roast beef-mustard', 'wheat-roast beef-mustard'
                 'rye-roast beef-ketchup', 'white-roast beef-ketchup', 'wheat-roast beef-ketchup' ]
```

and so on. The columns would be organized so the first column would be for the rye bread, the second column would be for the white bread, and the third column would be for the wheat bread. Is there a name for what I am trying to do? It also needs to work even if I add new things to each array. Thanks to anyone who answers!

Comment: Nested for in loops is what you are looking for

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? 
StackOverflow isn't a free code-writing service, and expects you to 
[try to solve your own problem first](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592). 
Please update your question to show what you have already tried, showing the specific problem you are facing in a 
[minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). 
For further information, please see 
[how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), 
and take the 
[tour of the site](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Answer (score 1):

Three nested for in loops, going over every combination:

```js
var bread = ['rye', 'white', 'wheat'];
var meat = ['roast beef', 'ham', 'turkey'];
var condiments = ['mayo', 'mustard', 'ketchup'];

for (var b in bread) {
    for (var m in meat) {
        for (var c in condiments) {
            console.log (bread[b] + "-" + meat[m] + "-" + condiments[c]); // Or wherever you want this result to go
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need one loop for each component.

**3 nested for loops**

```js
var bread=['rye', 'white', 'wheat'];
var meat = [ 'roast beef', 'ham', 'turkey'];
var condiments = [ 'mayo', 'mustard','ketchup'];

var result = [];
for(var i = 0; i < bread.length; i++) {
  result.push([]);
  for(var j = 0; j < bread.length; j++) {
    for(var k = 0; k < bread.length; k++) {
      result[i].push(bread[i] + '-' + meat[j] + '-' + condiments[k]);
    }
  }
}

console.log(result);
```

OR

**3 nested forEach loops**

```js
var bread=['rye', 'white', 'wheat'];
var meat = [ 'roast beef', 'ham', 'turkey'];
var condiments = [ 'mayo', 'mustard','ketchup'];

var result = [];
bread.forEach(function(b) {
  result.push([]);
  meat.forEach(function(m) {
    condiments.forEach(function(c) {
      result[result.length - 1].push(b + '-' + m + '-' + c);
    });
  })
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: This is almost exactly what I need. Is there any way to make the first column only rye combinations, the second column only white combinations, and the third column only wheat combinations?

Comment: I've updated the answer to include three sub arrays by bread type. Update your question to include this request.